# Can $10^{2k+1}+ 1$ be a perfect square?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For odd integers $n$, can you prove that $10^n+1$ is **not** a perfect square?

Comment: Regarding recent edits, if you'd like to ask about $3^n$, please ask a new, separate question.

Comment: EDit your statement because for $n=1$ you have a counterexample.

Answer (score 8):

Since $10\equiv1\pmod3$, it suffices to note that $1^n+1=2$ is not a quadratic residue modulo $3$. (We don't even need the assumption that $n$ is odd.)

Comment: I don't totally understand, but here's what I understood of what you said: Since 10 = 1 (mod 3), (10^n)+1 (mod 3) = 1^n + 1 (mod 3). If I understand you correctly, you imply that 2+3k (for some integer k) can not be a perfect square, but I don't know why that is true .  I'm a math novice trying to get better, so if you could explain your solution a bit more I'd really really appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: If $n \equiv 0 \pmod 3$ then $ n^2 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$ .                 If $n \equiv 1 \pmod 3$ then $n^2 \equiv 1^2 \equiv 1 \pmod 3 $ .         If $n \equiv 2 \pmod 3$ then $n^2 \equiv 2^2 \equiv 4 \equiv 1  \pmod 3 $ so $n^2$ is never $\equiv 2 \pmod 3$

Answer (score 7):

Lead the equation $10^n = (a-1)(a+1)$ to a contradiction. For instance the prime factor $5$ can appear only in one of those $2$ factors, so we have $5^n \leq a+1$, hence $(a-1)(a+1) \geq 5^n(5^n-2) > 10^n$, contradiction!

Answer (score 0):

> In general, let $a\in\mathbb{P}$ (prime numbers) and suppose $a^n+1$ is a perfect square for some $n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{1\}.$

Then there is $x\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $x^2=a^n+1$ and therefore $a^n=(x+1)(x-1).$ Then we can write $a^p=x+1$ and $a^q=x-1$ for some integers $p,q\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$ such that $p+q=n$ and $p>q.$ This clearly implies $a^p-a^q=2.$

- If $q=0,$ we get $a=3$ and $p=1$ which implies $$3^1+1=2^2.$$
- If $q\neq 0,$ we get $a=2$ and $p=2, q=1$ which implies $$2^3+1=3^2.$$